# How to implement license control in IIS hosted WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I am creating a new WCF service which should require a license to "work". I wonder how to go about implementing this without having a license check in every operation of the service contract.

Basically I want to do the license check upon initilization of the service. If I implement the license check in the service contract constructor, I am afraid it is going to act weird when hosted in IIS (which is going to be the primary host type).

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a 'clean' way to do this without something like an HTTP module in IIS. You can do it in a 'dirty' way by adding a constructor to your service file and doing something like this:

```
Public Sub New()
    If notLicensed then
        throw new Exception("Not Licensed")
    End if
End Sub
```

That is going to result in a lot of exceptions being passed back to clients (and it's actually going to check every time an instance of the service is created), but it doesn't require you to clutter up your service methods. That said, hopefully someone else has a better answer. :)

Comment: Yearh I kinda want to avoid that solution. I was wondering if it was feasible to implement a behavior class for doing this instead. That way I could probably throw a fault contract instead.